# About the remote "not"

Tags: negation

Not a native English speaker.
I noticed for a long time now some speakers use a second sentence consisting of a single word, "not", as a way to entirely negate the former sentence and generally in a humorous way.
For example: "I like your shirt. Not."
Is this correct English or just something people understand even though it is not grammatically correct?
I am asking this because in my native language, French, there is no way to negate this easily. I could translate "or not" (by "ou pas") but not just "not".
Any details about this separate "not", historical or linguistic will be appreciated.

Comment: I've always regarded this as a term from "Valley Speak", a California youth subculture that arose in the 80s.

Comment: The usual response these days is "the 1990s called. They want their 'Not!' back".

Comment: This came into popular use after it was used in a Saturday Night Live comedy sketch called "Wayne's world". Before that people would have understood it, but that's when the joke really took off.

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic nonstandard usage especially in informal, humorous contexts:

***[Not:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/not)***

> ​(humorous, informal) used to emphasize the opposite of a statement.

> *Well, that sounds like a fun evening—not!*

(oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com)

It usage dates back to the beginning of the 20th century but was made popular a few decades ago:

***[Not](https://www.etymonline.com/word/not)***:

> As an interjection to negate what was said before or reveal it as sarcasm, it is attested by 1900, popularized 1989 by "Wayne's World" sketches on "Saturday Night Live" TV show.

(Etymonline)

From: [American Speech](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455678?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)
Vol. 68, No. 2 (Summer, 1993), pp. 213
Published by: Duke University Press.

[image]

(jstor.org)

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure what your "yes" is an answer to because I offered two options. Are you saying this is grammatically correct English then, although informal?

Comment: It is an idiomatic nonstandard usage of not.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying.

Comment: The Japanese language has a similar construct that is often translated as: “- is what I’d like to say”.